# Rails create shared partial for buttons bar

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to create a shred partial with buttons for each page.

On views like suppliers/index I call:

```
<%= render 'shared/buttons-bar', :resource => supplier %>
```

And I tried on shared/buttons-bar

```
<%= link_to 'New', new_resource_path, class: 'btn btn-primary btn-md' %>
```

or:

```
<%= link_to send("new_#{resource}_path", resource) do %>
<% end %>
```

But does not work.

What is the right syntax?

Answer (score 1):

Just `:resource`:

```
<%= link_to 'New', resource, class: 'btn btn-primary btn-md' %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the right string in that interpolated method call. You can't just pass the object to send like that. You can try it in the console. Here I made `resource` a `User` object.

```
irb(main):022:0> include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
=> Object
irb(main):023:0> ApplicationController.helpers.link_to('New', send("new_#{resource.class.name.underscore}_path"))
=> "<a href=\"/user/new\">New</a>"
```